# How do I hide the Menu Bar after uninstalling Epson Easy Photo Print on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Epson Easy Photo Print is bloatware that installs this annoying toolbar into Windows 7's Explorer. It's hideous. Not only that, it forces the Menu Bar to display at all times. After uninstalling it, the Menu Bar cannot be disabled. I have tried checking and unchecking `Organize / Layout / Menu bar` and `Organize / Folder and search options / View / Advanecd settings: / Always show menus`. Neither of them disable the menu bar. The only option I have when right-clicking the menu bar is a horizontal rule followed by `Lock all toolbars`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Run Regedt32 (registry editor).
- Locate the toolbar location in your
  registry.  Click the + next to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE to expand it, expand SOFTWARE below that,
  etc. until you get down to
  "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbar." 
  You will see a list of GUIDs (codes). Locate
  {9421DD08-935F-4701-A9CA-22DF90AC4EA6} in the right pane .
- If you want to delete the toolbar, delete the GUID key.  But if you
  just want to disable it, you can rename it to
  XXX{9421DD08-935F-4701-A9CA-22DF90AC4EA6} , when you want to renable
  it, just rename it back to the original GUID.

Comment: Wow, thanks! What a quick response. How did you find out the GUID so fast?

Comment: Many years of learning how to research; glad it helped!

Comment: Well where did you start?

Comment: I think it was just "easy photo print toolbar"!

Comment: Ah, I see it now. It was good and hidden in someone's antivirus log.

Answer (score 2):

Old question but I found a more user friendly way was just to open up Internet Explorer and disable Easy Photo Print. Next time you open up an explorer window, the toolbar is gone!

Really bad show by Epson not cleaning this up. I uninstalled everything when I was cleaning a laptop and it still remained.

Comment: It's ironic that you gave this answer now, because just two weeks ago I had this issue again! It was funny Google searching to find my own question. I have to prefer @Debra's solution though, and the absolute eradication of Easy Photo Print from my computer and registry.

Answer (score 0):

@Coops already answered this old question, but just to complete: In Windows 10, it is possible to disable the toolbar even Internet Explorer is not enabled (on new installations it is by default). Just go to Control Panel - Internet Settings - Programs - Manage Extensions.